# How to store an array into a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store an array into a table but its not working it adds the table but it doesn't add the column name at all. It's just empty

Here's the entire code.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

  if(isset($_GET['NAME'])) {
  $sector = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['SECTORPOSITION']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['NAME']) ; // escape your variable here .
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $sector  (Name) VALUES ('$name') ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}

    if(isset($_GET['TYPE'])) {
    file_put_contents('contents.txt', $_GET['TYPE'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['ISEXPLORED'])) {
    file_put_contents('contents.txt', $_GET['ISEXPLORED'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'])) {
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name VARCHAR(30), Type VARCHAR(30), IsExplored VARCHAR(30), SectorPosition VARCHAR(30), guid VARCHAR(30))");
    }

    if(isset($_GET['GUID'])) {
    file_put_contents('contents.txt', $_GET['GUID'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    print('Added!');
?>
```

'RESOLVED THANKS TO ECHO'
'move the code of creating table first then insert to that table. you are inserting then creating table , you should do the opposite.'

Problem 2

Hey guys. I'm having an issue when I do

/test/test.php?SECTORPOSITION=13137&NAME=hibb&TYPE=Cluster&ISEXPLORED=true&GUID=13 I get a syntax error.

But when I do

?SECTORPOSITION=hey&NAME=hibb&TYPE=Cluster&ISEXPLORED=true&GUID=13 It works fine?

Here's my code.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
    if(isset($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'])) {
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name INT, Type VARCHAR(30), IsExplored VARCHAR(30), SectorPosition INT, guid INT)");
    }


  if(isset($_GET['TYPE'])) {
  $sector = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['SECTORPOSITION']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $type= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['TYPE']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['NAME']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $isexplored = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ISEXPLORED']) ; // escape your variable here 
  $guid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['GUID']) ; // escape your variable here 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $sector  (Name,Type,IsExplored,SectorPosition,guid) VALUES ('$name','$type','$isexplored','$sector','$guid') ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
    print('Added!');
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` functions anymore, they're deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: what @halloei said :)

Comment: you have checked if there is value in `$_GET['NAME']` ?

Comment: Read up about SQL injection as well

Comment: Also be carful with Sql Injection! I think it is wrong to put the field value in `\`` chars

Comment: Here's my parameter   http://rbx-interstellar.com/test/test.php?SECTORPOSITION=as7,1337,1337&NAME=TEST

Comment: The table name is as7,1337,1337 ... that can't be right?

Comment: IT creates tables on the go.                                              Here's the SECTORPOSITION code  if(isset($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'])) {
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name VARCHAR(30), Type VARCHAR(30), IsExplored VARCHAR(30), SectorPosition VARCHAR(30), guid VARCHAR(30))");
 }

Comment: Could you add the output of `var_export($_GET);` in your question?

Comment: where is the code of craeting table ?

Comment: Also, you're creating the table *after* the insert code.

Comment: @echo_Me It's right there in the fourth IF condition.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

look like I have an array

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);

json_encode($array);
```

and save the json encoded value

Its not standard to store array in db. You could see any cms, they would store it as json encoded objects, so that they can retrieve back the values

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: Its not standard to store array in db. You could see any cms, they would store it as json encoded objects, so that they can retrieve back the values

Comment: The reason I asked for this is that your answer was flagged for the length, could you please edit your answer and add this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `mysql_` functions anymore (its a sin!), use the improved. Use `mysqli_`. Like this:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if(isset($_GET['NAME'])) {
    $your_table_whitelist = array('table1', 'table2'); // list your tables
    if(!in_array($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'], $your_table_whitelist, true)) {
        exit; // no table like that found
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO {$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']} (Name) VALUES(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['NAME']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Things to point out:

- your current code is open to SQL injections, use MYSQLI and utilize parameterized queries instead.
- since you cannot bind tables inside, just create a whitelist of table to compare to your variable which will hold the table name. If it matches, its okay, it's not, just handle that error.

Comment: You don't really have to escape the `$sector_position` if you're going to check it against a white list ;-) I would also recommend a strict `in_array()` check.

Comment: @Jack wow thank you for that suggestion, that is much much better

Answer (score 0):

your code is very open to sql injection  you should go to mysqli or pdo.

```
if(isset($_GET['NAME'])) {
  $sector = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['SECTORPOSITION']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['NAME']) ; // escape your variable here .
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $sector  (Name) VALUES ('$name') ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
```

EDIT: you got this error

```
 Table 'TheGalaxy.at' doesn't exist
```

because you are creating table after the insert , so the table is not created yet.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Maybe its something I am doing wrong.                  Maybe its because of this [code] if(isset($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'])) {
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name VARCHAR(30), Type VARCHAR(30), IsExplored VARCHAR(30), SectorPosition VARCHAR(30), guid VARCHAR(30))");
 }[/code]

Comment: I'm going to guess that `$_GET['NAME']` is the array?

Comment: i dont know , its you who know , you should put your full code, i cant guess with your code.

Comment: Table 'TheGalaxy.at' doesn't exist Is the error I got

Comment: Hmm, the table name should rightfully be wrapped in backticks; not sure why you took that out. @echo_Me

Comment: you see ! . you have no table yet , you didnt create table. or you creating it under this code.

Comment: its not problem , it already thrown in the error that table is not created.

Comment: no not full , where is the code of creating the table `TheGalaxy.at`

Comment: move the code of creating table first then insert to that table. you are inserting then creating table , you should do the opposite.

Comment: @user3302898 if this answer helped you then make sure to accept this answer as solved .

Comment: Hey guys. I'm having another issue posted it in main post

Comment: problem is with your url Path . you have to ask new question for that.

Comment: if the main problem is solved then accept this answer , then ask new question.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use mysql function as they're deprecated, instead use mysqli.

the proper way to insert data into the database as follows :

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tableName values('".$_GET['NAME']."')");
```

where $link is your connection string. like

```
$link = ("myhost","myUser","myPassword","myDB");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you I'll take your advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_GET['NAME'])) {
  $sql= "INSERT INTO ".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."(name) VALUES(".$_GET['NAME'].")";
 mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.