# Syntax Error when using numbers? PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm having an issue when I do

```
/test/test.php?SECTORPOSITION=13137&NAME=hibb&TYPE=Cluster&ISEXPLORED=true&GUID=13
```

I get a syntax error.

But when I do

```
?SECTORPOSITION=hey&NAME=hibb&TYPE=Cluster&ISEXPLORED=true&GUID=13
```

It works fine?

Here's my code.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
    if(isset($_GET['SECTORPOSITION'])) {
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name INT, Type VARCHAR(30), IsExplored VARCHAR(30), SectorPosition INT, guid INT)");
    }


  if(isset($_GET['TYPE'])) {
  $sector = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['SECTORPOSITION']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $type= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['TYPE']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['NAME']) ; // escape your variable here .
  $isexplored = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ISEXPLORED']) ; // escape your variable here 
  $guid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['GUID']) ; // escape your variable here 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $sector  (Name,Type,IsExplored,SectorPosition,guid) VALUES ('$name','$type','$isexplored','$sector','$guid') ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
    print('Added!');
?>
```

Comment: *"when I do `{...}` I get a syntax error."* - Being?

Comment: For one thing, I see `Name INT` then I see `&NAME=hibb` that's not an `int`

Comment: If you're not already using error reporting (which you should), add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It's pretty worrying that you're programatically creating tables. There is almost *never* a good reason to do this, unless you're actually writing a front-end for managing your database itself. Generally, if you find yourself creating tables, your architecture is *very* broken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store an array into a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548277/how-to-store-an-array-into-a-table)

Answer (score 4):

Your queries are inconsistent:

```
 mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$_GET['SECTORPOSITION']."` ( Name 
                           ^---                        ^---

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $sector  (Name,Typ
                         ^^^^^^^---- no backticks
```

So your first query would be

```
CREATE TABLE `12345` ...
```

and then the second becomes

```
INSERT INTO 12345
```

which will be a flat-out syntax error.

And note that dynamically creating tables like this is usually the sign of a horribly bad design. Since the fields are the same between all the tables, your "table name" should just become another field in the SAME table:

e.g. `positions (id, sectorposition, name, etc.....)`

Comment: I was just thinking of that too, saw it (the logic here) when I reloaded.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1 for "usually the sign of a horribly bad design." Dynamic table creation based on a query parameter sounds like a security disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: As this logic explains and if I may quote [the manual on identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html) - *"Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."* - Hence, the error.